# Numpy array of np.float32 type setting incorrect data

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

Here is the following code that I am using

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime


a = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d")
arr = []
for i in range(0,100):
    b = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d")+timedelta(days=i), "%Y-%m-%d")
    arr.append(b)

nparr = np.zeros([100],dtype=np.float32)
alist = [0]*100
for x,i in enumerate(nparr):
    val = int(arr[x].replace("-",""))
    nparr[x] = val
    alist[x] = val
    
print(nparr)
print(alist)
```

To explain the code above, I am basically making an array called arr which has dates in the format string from todays date till 100 days from today, the array looks something like ["2022-05-31", "2022-06-01"....]. Then I initialize a numpy array called nparr, and then I loop through the nparr and then basically convert the arr string value into a float by first removing the dashes and then using the python float function. I am also using a list called alist and basically adding to this list same way I am adding to the nparr list.

The output that I am getting for alist is this below. This is the expected result, and I was hoping to get the same result for nparr but this is not what I am getting for nparr:

```
[20220601, 20220602, 20220603, 20220604, 20220605, 20220606, 20220607, 20220608, 20220609, 20220610, 20220611, 20220612, 20220613, 20220614, 20220615, 20220616, 20220617, 20220618, 20220619, 20220620, 20220621, 20220622, 20220623, 20220624, 20220625, 20220626, 20220627, 20220628, 20220629, 20220630, 20220701, 20220702, 20220703, 20220704, 20220705, 20220706, 20220707, 20220708, 20220709, 20220710, 20220711, 20220712, 20220713, 20220714, 20220715, 20220716, 20220717, 20220718, 20220719, 20220720, 20220721, 20220722, 20220723, 20220724, 20220725, 20220726, 20220727, 20220728, 20220729, 20220730, 20220731, 20220801, 20220802, 20220803, 20220804, 20220805, 20220806, 20220807, 20220808, 20220809, 20220810, 20220811, 20220812, 20220813, 20220814, 20220815, 20220816, 20220817, 20220818, 20220819, 20220820, 20220821, 20220822, 20220823, 20220824, 20220825, 20220826, 20220827, 20220828, 20220829, 20220830, 20220831, 20220901, 20220902, 20220903, 20220904, 20220905, 20220906, 20220907, 20220908]
```

Instead I for the nparr value I am getting:

```
[20220600. 20220602. 20220604. 20220604. 20220604. 20220606. 20220608.
 20220608. 20220608. 20220610. 20220612. 20220612. 20220612. 20220614.
 20220616. 20220616. 20220616. 20220618. 20220620. 20220620. 20220620.
 20220622. 20220624. 20220624. 20220624. 20220626. 20220628. 20220628.
 20220628. 20220630. 20220700. 20220702. 20220704. 20220704. 20220704.
 20220706. 20220708. 20220708. 20220708. 20220710. 20220712. 20220712.
 20220712. 20220714. 20220716. 20220716. 20220716. 20220718. 20220720.
 20220720. 20220720. 20220722. 20220724. 20220724. 20220724. 20220726.
 20220728. 20220728. 20220728. 20220730. 20220732. 20220800. 20220802.
 20220804. 20220804. 20220804. 20220806. 20220808. 20220808. 20220808.
 20220810. 20220812. 20220812. 20220812. 20220814. 20220816. 20220816.
 20220816. 20220818. 20220820. 20220820. 20220820. 20220822. 20220824.
 20220824. 20220824. 20220826. 20220828. 20220828. 20220828. 20220830.
 20220832. 20220900. 20220902. 20220904. 20220904. 20220904. 20220906.
 20220908. 20220908.]
```

Why is this? This seems very buggy and I am not quite sure how to fix this. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: `np.float32` doesn't have the precision you are looking for. Is there any particular reason you can't use integer types?

Comment: This is actually not exactly the code that I am using, the code that I am using is much complex, I just abstracted out the error and wrote this simple program to highlight the issue. In my actual code I need it to be float type. regardless, I solved the issue I realized that python float are 64 bit, so I can't just use a numpy array of type np.float32, so I instead of using dtype=np.float32, I just use dtype=float.

Comment: As pointed out, it is a precision problem. Further, I'd strongly advice against representing days as ints in this way. They lose all semantics. It becomes hard to compute the number of days between two instants, for example. Consider using Julian Date instead. If you want to stick to float32 you could use Reduced JD. You have good library functions for this in pandas and similar libraries.